# commit code without changing svn blame/annotate information

Tags: svn

I'm working on a huge project that uses SVN and lately we've introduced some changes to our coding standard.
Now my question is: Is it possible to commit changes like adding spaces where necessary or change tabs to spaces without disturbing svn blame/svn annotate informations?

Example:
I have now something like:

```
  5061    someone     return SUCCESS;
  5061    someone }
  6904   someone2
  6904   someone2 int someFunction(long seqNum)
  6904   someone2 {
  6904   someone2     void* msg_buffer = NULL;
  6904   someone2     Address source = AddressGet(someId,messageIdGet());
```

and I would like to add a space and move asteriks from left to right

```
  5061    someone     return SUCCESS;
  5061    someone }
  6904   someone2
  6904   someone2 int someFunction(long seqNum)
  6904   someone2 {
  7123         me     void *msg_buffer = NULL;
  7123         me     Address source = AddressGet(someId, messageIdGet());
```

Can I do that but leave svn annotate/ svn blame information pointing to "someone2" instead of "me"?

Answer (score 1):

No, your commit will always be part of history, and by default it will affect the blame output. I'm not even certain you want to: what if you make a mistake while applying these standards changes?

However, you can use options on *blame* to ignore the whitespace. In particular, `svn blame` accepts the [--extensions flag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.extensions), so you can do this (for example):

```
svn blame --extensions --ignore-all-space file.c
```

Comment: To also ignore changes in line break style, use `svn blame --extensions "--ignore-all-space --ignore-eol-style" file.c`

Answer (score 0):

1. Each SVN revision have 3 default unversioned properties

> ```
> svn:author
> svn:date
> svn:log
> ```

2. You can change revision-property:

   - from client-side, using second form of [propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) (but anyway, correct pre-revprop-change hook must be created on repository-side): [detailed description](https://blog.tinned-software.net/change-author-of-last-svn-commit/)
   - from repository-side, using [svnadmin setrevprop](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setrevprop.html)